# Force Glassfish4 to use Jackson instead of Moxy

Tags: glassfish, jersey, jackson, moxy

Glassfish4 is using Moxy to serialize REST responses into JSON. Does anybody know how to configure application to use Jackson instead of Moxy?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to register [JacksonFeature](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/jackson/JacksonFeature.html) in your application if you want to use Jackson as your JSON provider (by registering this feature your disable MOXy to be your JSON provider).

You can do it either in `Application` subclass:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

        // Add root resources.
        classes.add(HelloWorldResource.class);

        // Add JacksonFeature.
        classes.add(JacksonFeature.class);

        return classes;
    }
}
```

or in `ResourceConfig`:

```
final Application application = new ResourceConfig()
        .packages("org.glassfish.jersey.examples.jackson")
        .register(MyObjectMapperProvider.class)  // No need to register this provider if no special configuration is required.
        // Register JacksonFeature.
        .register(JacksonFeature.class);
```

See [Jackson](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson) section in Jersey Users Guide for more information.

Comment: Where can I find Jackson class location?

Comment: `JacksonFeature` is in `org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jakson`. This module brings Jackson 1.9.x with it. If you want to use Jackson 2.x simply add dependency on `com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider` and it will be automatically enabled thanks to `META-INF/services` mechanism.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23730062/use-iso-8601-dates-in-jax-rs-responses) for complete instructions to achieve this on GlassFish 4 with a Maven build.

Answer (score 4):

Answer by Michal Gajdos is correct, just to add to that, add this dependency in your pom.xml ,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I also add it to pom.xml and start glassfish 4.1. it is still keep jackson version 2.3.2 (default of glassfish)