# Springboot read from json file in resources then return exact same data without manipulating data

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I have a json file that contains static data and i want to create a springboot service that returns the content of that file. Thus far i have managed to just connect to the file but im not sure how to return the json data.

This is the json:

```
{
"carrots": [ 1, 2, 5, 10, 12.5, 20, 50 ],
 "apple": [ 100, 500, 750, 900 ],
 "orange": [200, 500, 1000],
 "lemon": [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 25],
 "peanuts": [200, 500, 1000]
}
```

This is some schedo code to what i am trying to achieve :

```
public JsonInformationHereAsReturnType getJsonContent() {

    File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:sample.json");

            //Read File Content
            String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));

    return content;
}
```

After runing the code i want to just get back the same json i.e

```
{
"carrots": [ 1, 2, 5, 10, 12.5, 20, 50 ],
 "apple": [ 100, 500, 750, 900 ],
 "orange": [200, 500, 1000],
 "lemon": [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 25],
 "peanuts": [200, 500, 1000]
}
```

> How do i achieve this result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have already got the Json String in your code.If you want to get a Json Object,you just parse from it.

```
@Test
public void test() {
    getJson("classpath:sample.json");
}

public JSON getJson(String path) {
    File file = null;
    try {
        file = ResourceUtils.getFile(path);
        //Read File Content
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
        //Get a Json String
        System.out.println(content);
        JSON json = JSON.parseObject(content);
        return json;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I am failing to get this method to work, i cannot find JSON , where do i import it from.

Comment: I figured it, So i just needed to return the parsed object

Answer (score 0):

I have found this quick and simple REST API that returns JSON as a response, you might want to take a look and pattern to this.

[how to return json objects from java rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26849356/how-to-return-json-objects-from-java-rest-api)

Comment: i dont think thats related to the question i have, in my case i just want to read and return the json file contents.