# Custom JSON marshalling with JAX-RS on Glassfish/Payara

Tags: java, json, glassfish, jax-rs, payara

I am curious to know which JSON marshalling/unmarshalling framework is used by Glassfish/Payara is case of JAX-RS and how I can add custom JSON mapper class into it.

I would like to write a custom serializer for my `Enum` class. I use `provided` scope in my pom.xml for jaxrs `javaee-api` 7.0 so default Glassfish libraries are used.

I tried to use `@JsonValue` and wrote a class which implements `javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter` and `JsonSerializer<T>` as well. Do not work either as I expect.

This is my enum class:

```
public enum ErrorCode {
    MY_ERROR(123456);

    private int value;

    ErrorCode(final int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public int  getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

The class which uses enum:

```
public class ErrorInfo {
    private ErrorCode errorCode;

    public String toJson() {
        try {
            return new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(this);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            // TODO: do something here...
        }
    }
}
```

And the JAX-RS class where I would like to send back the `ErrorInfo` instance as a JSON:

```
@Provider
public class MyExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Throwable throwable) {
        ...
        return Response
                .status(errorInfo.getHttpStatus())
                .type(ExtendedMediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .entity(errorInfo)
                .build();
    }
}
```

If I use the code above then the `errorCode` value is "MY_ERROR" string instead of the int 123456 value.

If I use my extra `errorInfo.toJson()` method then @JsonValue annotation does the magic but I would like to avoid writing extra code to handle enum serialization issue.

What is the proper way to configure / add extra enum mapper class to the default JAX-RS JSON library in Glassfish/Payara?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Payara Server uses [MOXy](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#json.moxy) to map to/from JSON. You can use an alternative like Jackson, if you add Jackson to your app and add `JacksonFeature` into JAX-RS classes: [Force Glassfish4 to use Jackson instead of Moxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317927/force-glassfish4-to-use-jackson-instead-of-moxy#18318314)

In the upcoming Payara 5, which will support Java EE 8, JSON marshalling will be handled in a standard way prescribed by the [JSON-Binding](http://json-b.net/)

Comment: Do you know how can I enable Jackson? I added org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson dependency to my pom but I get org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: WELD-001334: Unsatisfied dependencies for type ObjectProvider<FilterProvider> with qualifiers @Default

Comment: I linked the answer how to do it in my answer above. Here's the link again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317927/force-glassfish4-to-use-jackson-instead-of-moxy#18318314

Comment: I have tried that but it does not work for me: https://groups.google.com/forum/?__hssc=229474563.7.1507570987948&__hstc=229474563.f77c21f0c7f2189af2c0f0d9b585b87f.1497363477167.1507219438875.1507570987948.4&__hsfp=2561377333&hsCtaTracking=ee96a587-4450-4296-b986-ac67f6da0574%7Cff3c7a3b-1cde-4e52-b2ad-e162643b9683#!topic/payara-forum/p7JlVgTc7EI

Comment: @zappee i had the same issue but i was lucky enough that i had an old project that works. what causes UnsatisfiedResolutionException for me was jersey-media-json-jackson version 2.26 i changed it back to 2.10.4 and i no longer have this Exception