# How to use Jackson 2 in Payara 5?

Tags: jax-rs, jsonb, jackson2, payara, payara-micro

I'm using Jackson 2 with Payara 4 and I would liked to use **Jackson 2 in Payara 5**.

Using JAX-RS, I also would like to avoid changing annotations and so on...

In Payara 5 the default Jsonb provider is Yasson. 
Any ideas to disable it and use Jackson instead? All comments/ideas are welcome :-)

**NB:** Yasson is very interesting but handle abstract class or interface serialization/deserialization is a little more complex than putting a Jackson annotation.
My current understanding is that it requires to implement a JsonbSerializer/Deserializer but actually the serializer/deserializer is only available on field/method (an issue is opened for class, which will be very helpful).
Anyway, migrating to Yasson will mean implementing many serializer/deserializer as required (for entities and of course collections) but I guess it's a hard stuff.

Comment: How do you use Jackson 2 with Payara 4? If you enable Jackson 2 in Payara 5 it should automatically disable the default Jsonb provider. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18318314/784594

Comment: Well, I've just added Jackson's 2.8.9 dependencies in my pom.xml and disabled the default moxyJson provider in my web.xml.

Comment: What do you get if you do the same with Payara 5? I think that adding Jackson disables the JSON-B provider automatically.

Comment: Nothing. It uses JSON-B (Yasson) and I actually can't find a way to bypass it.

Comment: Is it the expected behavior or there is an improvement?

Comment: Looking at the source code, Jersey won't register another feature if there's one already registered. I thought that a feature provided by your app would take precedence but it's not the case. Moxy provides a special property to disable it but JsonB feature doesn't. Still, it's possible to prefer a specific feature by setting `jersey.config.jsonFeature` property to the specific feature, which is `JacksonFeature` for Jackson. I'll add a detailed answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the property `jersey.config.jsonFeature` to `JacksonFeature` so that the default JsonB feature isn't registered.

You can set it either in the code by overriding the `Application.getProperties()` method, or set the property in web.xml as `context-param`:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>jersey.config.jsonFeature</param-name>
  <param-value>JacksonFeature</param-value>
</context-param>
```

If your Jersey Servlet is explicitly declared at web.xml (either as javax.ws.rs.core.Application or a as custom subclass), then use init-param instead, within the Jersey Application servlet declaration:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.jsonFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>JacksonFeature</param-value>
    </init-param>
    ...
</servlet>
```

You also need to add Jackson dependencies into your application - but you have probably done that already so ignore this.

Explanation:

The MOXy feature provides a property `jersey.config.disableMoxyJson` to disable it. The JsonB feature default in Payara 5 doesn't provide such property but will not register itself if `jersey.config.jsonFeature` property exists and is not `JsonBindingFeature`. The same property works for all Jersey features so setting it to `JacksonFeature` will allow only the JacksonFeature to be registered.

Comment: Hi Ondrej. Does it mean I need to add "org.glassfish.jersey" dependencies as well? JacksonFeature is not located in com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs or whatever jackson provider you may have. Do you have a web.xml example?

Comment: Well, you will feel happy to know it works... but I'm surprised. I didn't add the mentioned dependencies and it works. You will find hereunder an extract from my `web.xml`

Comment: `<init-param>
          <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
          <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature</param-value>
      </init-param>`

Comment: `<init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
          <param-value>
              fr.trendev.comptandye.services,
              com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs <!-- Jackson providers -->
          </param-value>
      </init-param>`

Comment: I don't understand why but `org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature` is not imported and it works. Does it mean that the parser will just analyze the property... without checking if the file/class is present? **Amazing and strange hack ;)**

Comment: This was such a pain I had `getClasses` overriden and lost the auto-discover. Where does someone find these configuration at? I was all over payar's site

Comment: You shouldn't need to set the `jersey.config.server.provider.packages` parameter. This parameter overrides the `getClasses` method and the autodiscovery mechanism. Also, instead of `jersey.config.server.provider.classnames` init-param, you can use `jersey.config.jsonFeature` context-param - see an example in my updated reply

Comment: Since your app used Jackson on Payara 4, it already contains all required Jackson dependencies, including `org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature` - check your application's WEB-INF/classes folder in the WAR file.

Comment: Hi @OndrejM, I've finally just overridden the getProperties method and removed my messy web.xml file and it works. Thanks a lot for your support and your explanation ;)

Comment: Hi @JulienSié, I'm happy that you finally made your app work! You can now mark this answer as the correct answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If your Jersey Servlet is explicitly declared at web.xml (either as javax.ws.rs.core.Application or a as custom subclass), then use init-param instead, within the Jersey Application servlet declaration:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.jsonFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>JacksonFeature</param-value>
    </init-param>
...
</servlet>
```