# How do I go about registering jackson-datatype-joda in a glassfish / payara REST server

Tags: java, glassfish, jodatime, payara

I have a REST endpoint in a container (Payara 4)
I have added the dependency to the pom.xml for the joda serialization extension.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
     <version>2.10.3</version>
</dependency>
```

But I get the items serialized incorrectly.

> `"dt":{"chronology":{},"millis":1499896800000}`

I know I need to use jackson-databind-joda, but I am not sure how to **register it correctly in PAYARA**. There are examples for Spring Boot, but not for the older application servers?

```
@Path("bom")
@Stateless
public class ProductionMaterialRestEndpoint {

    @POST
    @Path("kw/compare/{year}/{week}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ResultContainingDateTime compare(
            @PathParam("year") int year,
            @PathParam("week") int week) throws IOException, ExecutionException {

            ...               
    }    
}


public class ResultContainingDataTime {
    private org.joda.time.DateTime dt;
}
```

how do I register the joda serializer module with the serializer built into PAYARA /GLASSFISH

Comment: which Java EE version are you using? Payara or Glassfish don't use Jackson out-of-the-box. Did you manually configure Jackson to be used as the message body writer/reader for JSON payload?

Comment: we are using payara 4.1.2.181

Comment: I think you might be on to something, I think it's using JAX-RS and not jackson, so how would I fix the serialization then?

Answer (score 0):

JAX-RS is basically the [specification](https://rieckpil.de/whatis-jakarta-restful-web-services-jax-rs/) on how to write REST web services in Java EE. It does not specify which technology is used to serialize messages but only the interface `MessageBodyReader` and `MessageBodyReader`.

If you use Java EE 8, you'll get [JSON-B](https://rieckpil.de/whatis-json-binding-json-b/) (Binding) that ensures JSON serialization out-of-the-box. If you want to use Jackson instead, you need to configure it ([How to use Jackson 2 in Payara 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49793289/how-to-use-jackson-2-in-payara-5)). Furthermore, you don't get the default auto-configuration of Jackson modules (e.g. Java Time, Joda Time) out-of-the-box like for Spring Boot and have to register them for your `ObjectMapper` by yourself.

If your code is using Java 8 and Java EE 8, you can also use the `java.time` classes like `LocalDateTime`, `Instant`, etc. and use JSON-B annotations to specify how you want to serialize these values using `@JsonbDateFormat`

Comment: do you perhaps know how I would register them with the `ObjectMapper` so that all JAX-RS responses use the configured mapper?