# Jackson 2.x - Flattening of nested lists

Tags: rest, jackson, jersey

I am upgrading from Jersey1.x to Jersey2.x. The REST web-service has a `List<List<String>>`  which with 1.x was returning the response as:

```
"values" :[  
   [  
      "Value1_1",
      "Value1_2",
      "Value1_3"
   ],
   [  
      "Value2_1",
      "Value2_2",
      "Value2_3"
   ],
   [  
      "Value3_1",
      "Value3_2",
      "Value3_3"
   ]
]
```

With 2.x, it flattens out the inner list and response shows up as:

```
"values" : [
    "Value1_1 Value1_2 Value1_3",
    "Value2_1 Value2_2 Value2_3",
    "Value3_1 Value3_2 Value3_3"
]
```

(@JsonUnwrapped has not been added).

Assuming that we have to continue working with this type which produces a list if strings (and not change to List which produces a list of objects), how can we achieve a similar output.

Answer (score 0):

Jackson would not produce this result. When I tested with [MOXy](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#json.moxy) as the provider though, I did get this result. Make sure you are using Jackson and not MOXy. If you have `jersey-media-moxy` as dependency, remove it. Make sure you have the `jersey-media-json-jackson` dependency. And register the `JacksonFeature`.

Comment: Ahh... You are absolutely right.Thanks for pointing me in right direction. After getting your input i read this link to get things working: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317927/force-glassfish4-to-use-jackson-instead-of-moxy